# Is there an elegant way to redirect Default.aspx to either Home.aspx or Login.aspx?

Tags: asp.net

The way I have it now, Default.aspx is empty and has a code behind to Default.aspx.cs, which either redirects them to Login.aspx or Home.aspx depending on if the request is authenticated or not.

Default.aspx is just out there doing nothing. It just seems like there ought to be a more elegant approach to this.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Have you tried renaming your Home.aspx as Default.aspx and denying access to Default.aspx in web.config and letting the formsauthentication infrastructure do the redirect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the most elegant way to do this is to make use of web.config. You can specify, the login page here that the unauthenticated user will automatically be redirected to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LogOn.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Apart from this, you can also specify which users are granted access to pages in current folder through the authorization tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, IIS needs that placeholder to know it's there to serve as the default document.

EDIT: While it is technically possible to change these, it's just not worth it in the long run. Much better to follow convention and move home.aspx to default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a configured at the IIS level; meaning, you can configure the `Default` landing page of your app to be `Home.aspx`. And `Home.aspx` should automatically redirect to `Login.aspx` if the user is not logged in. See below screenshot from IIS Manager:

[image]

Select your WebApp from the list --> Double click on "Default Document".